How is God's omnipotence compatible with His inability to sin/do evil?
Consider a very powerful agent (call him John), who can perform every logically possible action, except for turning on my TV. Due to his nature, John just cannot do that. It seems to me that nobody would call John omnipotent, due to his inability to turn on my TV.
Now consider God. According to what I've read about classical Christian theism, it is impossible for God to sin/do evil due to his good divine nature. So how is God omnipotent when John isn't? What is the relevant difference between the 2 cases?
Consider another agent (call him Alex). Alex, unlike God, doesn't have a perfectly good nature, so he is able to sin and to do evil, in addition to everything that God can do. It seems like Alex is more omnipotent than God (he is able to perform actions that God cannot), which would make God not omnipotent, since nothing can be more omnipotent than an omnipotent being.
I would really like to know then, according to classical Christian theism how come God is omnipotent, while John and Alex are not.

Welcome to C.SE.  This is a site for Christian theology.  I see there is someone else vote-close your question for "off topic" (it's not me).  So one way to improve your question is to make it "on topic".  In this instance it's by making it not purely a philosophy of religion question (which you can also ask at Philosophy.SE), but asking for Christian view explicitly, for instance, "According to classical Christian theism, how come God is omnipotent, while John and Alex are not".

Thanks! I've just edited the question.

Welcome to the site, SuperFlash. This is a type of question often asked on here, with slight variations. Please go to this link and look at the answer by AlanD as he explains a faulty premise behind most of these questions. In view of that, you might want to change your illustrations (or drop them altogether). Here is the link: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/60952/what-is-the-biblical-basis-that-god-cannot-act-against-his-nature

@SuperFlash not really an answer, but you can switch the concept from starting with assumptions of the world and start with God you get a God who is capable of anything - then "good" is defined as things that God would do, "evil" being defined as things that God would not do, even though he could do anything.

It all depends on how you define good and evil.  If "good" is defined as whatever God chooses then by definition, everything he does is good.  It's God's universe to do with as he wishes.  Without God, I don't think philosophy has any better or less axiomatic/arbitrary definitions of good/evil.

Secular Definition: An omnipotent being is one who has unlimited power and is able to do anything:

having unlimited power; able to do anything. - Oxford Languages

having the power to do anything: - Cambridge Dictionary

almighty; having unlimited power or authority - Merriam-Webster



And I heard as it were the voice of a great multitude, and as the voice of many waters, and as the voice of mighty thunderings, saying, Alleluia: for the Lord God omnipotent reigneth. - Revelation 19:6

Biblical definition:  The name Pantokrator means All Holding.It is most often translated as Almighty. It expresses "the capacity for, not the exercise of power"
There are two things which need to be brought to bear on this question:

Having the power to do anything and the doing of the 'anything' are separate and the blurring of the two is a category error.  One can have the power to throw a rock through a window and yet not do it.  Refraining from an activity does not demonstrate lack of power but restraint, which is a demonstration of power.  Put another way, it shows having power over one's power.

A Christian understanding of sin/evil must be brought to bear in answering this question.  At it's heart Evil is not a thing in itself but, rather, it is a lack of goodness, much like darkness is merely a lack of light and not a thing in and of itself.  Likewise, Sin is not (at it's heart) an action but it is a disposition of the rejection of God.  Sin manifests in actions but is not merely those actions, themselves


To do evil, God would have to cease being Good for that is what evil is.  To commit sin He would have to deny Himself for that is what sin is.  These are not ultimately exertions of power but lapses in power.  One does not exert power to be evil; one simply refrains from exerting power of good.
Therefore, God can be omnipotent (possessing unlimited power and able to do anything) while at the same time not willing or intending to do certain things.  God does not refrain from certain things because He lacks power but because He has power to do all that He desires.  Not "doing" sin or evil is a demonstration of God's omnipotence.

It seems to me that nobody would call John omnipotent, due to his inability to turn on my TV.  Correct.  If John were omnipotent he would have the ability to turn on the TV and perhaps not desire to do so.
Alex, unlike God, doesn't have a perfectly good nature, so he is able to sin and to do evil, in addition to everything that God can do.  Incorrect.  If Alex "does" evil then he has ceased to be good and therefore cannot do everything God can do (which is be always good).  It is because Alex does not have a perfectly good nature that he cannot refrain from doing some evil.  He lacks the power to be only, always good.

Great, important distinctions: capacity (maybe the "potent" etymologically refers to potentia (potential); should we re-term it as omnipotentia?) vs. power to exercise restraint vs. pantokrator / sustaining power.  +1

What is your source for "all holding"? Everything points to kratos meaning strength, power, might.

Evil being not a thing and thus God would be less good if He had the capacity to sin is the correct point to highlight; distinguishing the capacity from the exercise is not. God doesn't have even the capacity to do evil, but He is not compelled to do everything which is possible.

@eques "From (1) the prefix πας (pas), all, and (2) the verb κρατεω (krateo), to hold or hold on."  "The verb κρατεω (krateo) means to hold on or hold in one's power. Noun κρατος (kratos) describes that holding or holding on. But note that these words do not so much describe force and coercion but rather a mastery and even intimacy. The related noun καρτερος (karteros) describes inner strength, patience and mastery."

@eques It is indeed impossible for God to lie or to deny Himself, for example.  However, does He lack the capacity to do so in His power or is it a matter of His Divine will and self control?  I'm sure Divine Simplicity would say this cannot be parsed out.  This is why I pointed out that He has power over His power.

This answer misses the obvious point that to sin is to will contrary to what God wills. Classical definitions of omnipotence bind God's power to what is logically possible: He cannot create a contradiction. Hence, since it is logically impossible for God to will what is contrary to His own will (as indeed, it is impossible for any rational agent to will against his own will), He cannot sin. It's not merely that God would need to deny Himself, which seems at least logically possible, but that He would have to choose what He does not choose. A clear logical contradiction.

@MikeBorden except κρατεω comes from κράτος (power, might) so you've inverted the derivations. The verb that means to hold also means to rule or command because it derives from the noun meaning power.

@jaredad7 except you have to avoid the voluntarism implications of God acting against his own will.

@jaredad7 "God can be omnipotent (possessing unlimited power and able to do anything) while at the same time not willing or intending to do certain things."

@eques This is what I find:  "The noun κρατος (kratos) and associated verb κρατεω (krateo) express holding on, holding in one's power, having power over, or master in the sense of absorbing something into one self — and this usually via some agent. These words come from an ancient root that means just that and ultimately derives from a group of word that has to do with being hard and inflexible."

@eques "But where our modern word "power" brings to mind some blunt and coercing force, the Greek noun κρατος (kratos) reflects a calm and intelligent kind of control; a giving kind of mastery that comes from an intimate knowledge of whatever is directed."  It's not disassociated from power but holding is primary, by means of power.

@MikeBorden what is your source for that? I was checking Ancient Greek dictionaries (https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=krate/w) and hold is way under the 4th definition.

@eques I originally found it here https://www.abarim-publications.com/DictionaryG/k/k-r-a-t-o-sfin.html.  It's a fairly long entry but more in depth than many dictionaries.  It's good to survey a bunch of them IMHO.   The first definition you linked says "absolute rule, hold sway".  Strong's has it primarily (literally or figuratively) as vigor with power being 3rd or 4th on the list.  Ultimately, I think it is not just power indicated by this word, but power held under control.

Interesting. Doing nothing would actually be the sign of ultimate power, including over oneself. I really like that theology! I'll present it to my spouse next time she asks me to take out the garbage.

@MikeBorden interesting source --- note that that is not a general Greek dictionary source, but some website pushing an interpretation of Scripture as a way to "transcend religion"

@Peter-ReinstateMonica  Self control over the power of snark is a thing :)

@eques Yeah.  Most of their "theological" articles aren't worth reading but the etymology is generally sound.

@MikeBorden How can you tell? Or rather by what basis do you evaluate their etymology as sound especially when it conflicts with more typical sources like Liddell and Scott?

@eques Look at a bunch of them and see the similarities.  I really don't see a difference between this and the Liddell Scott entry you linked.  In fact, I think LSJ supports what Abarim is saying.  Keep in mind that LSJ is a general ancient greek dictionary whereas Abarim zeroes in on Biblical usage.  In LSJ, the main root is to be strong, powerful but there are no biblical references until you get to section A IV, lay hold of, where the refs. are Genesis 19:16 (LXX), Matthew 9:25, Mark 9:27.


Sin is defined as breaking the Law.
The Law represents God's will.
For God to sin, he'd have to do something against his own will.

So, the question is basically asking about the ability to willfully do something against one's own will, something that by definition is impossible for everyone (like a four-sided triangle, or eating your cake and having it too).
God's inability to sin is not a restriction on his capability; it is a fact by definition.

The start of the answer seems like voluntarism, which is not necessarily a broadly Christian viewpoint. The point like "four-sided triangle" hints at a slightly different view which may be more broadly accepted.

The problem is that if God's will was less restrictive, he would be able to sin. So it seems like a non-omnibenevolent agent (Alex) would be more omnipotent, than an omnibenevolent agent (God), because omnibenevolence restricts some of God's actions.

@SuperFlash No, you are simply equating omnipotence with the quantity of things doable.

Well yeah, that seems like a really natural definition of omnipotence. But anyways, my question was resolved by Mike Borden in the answer above.

@SuperFlash There is no issue/restriction on God's will here.  Rather, the point is that "Evil" is being defined as "doing something that goes against God's will".  However, the moment that God decides to do something, doing it is His will.  So it stops being against His will, and thus stops being "Evil".  Can you drink a drink that no one has ever been about to drink?  No — because you have to be about to drink before you do drink it, meaning that it stops qualifying before you actually start drinking it.  The restriction is not on God, it is on "Evil".

@Chronocidal +1. Another good explaination that I like. It makes the point of restriction on "evil" very clear.

Interesting take: Mathematicians would call that an axiom, a primary given that is the basis of all that follows. For example, the neutral element regarding addition of integers is 0; that a+0=a for all a is not a defect of 0, it is its definition.

Frame Issue
I find the other answers agreeable, however... there is a fundamental issue with the question. The God you are describing is "middle sized" because it is fundamentally constrained by your understanding of the concept of "omnipotent". The question is a semantic issue.
So while we can debate the nature of God, or the definition of sin... ultimately the source of all Power, Truth, Love, etc... is God.
God can do anything consistent with His nature and essence. So he cannot lie, break a promise, deny his existence... etc.


"It would appear to be a minimal requirement for a being worthy of worship that he be greater than any other being. No other being exceeds God in power, knowledge or goodness. But this requirement is indeed minimal, since theists usually hold that God is not only greater than any other being as a matter of fact, but that it is impossible that there should ever be a being greater than God. God's power, knowledge and goodness are therefore seen not merely as very great but as maximal. God is omnipotent; he possesses all the power a being can have. God is omniscient; he knows everything which it is possible for a being to know. God is morally perfect; his goodness is unsurpassable.
Another way of expressing God's greatness is to say that he is infinite, or unlimited. These terms must, however, be understood in a qualified sense. To say that God is infinite in power does not mean that he can literally do anything. It has usually been held, for example, that God cannot create a square circle or a person with a morally free will who is determined always to choose what is morally right. The reason for this is not that God lacks some power or ability he might have had, but that these conceptions are logically contradictory and therefore impossible or even meaningless. God's power is the power to do anything which is logically possible. In addition, most theists hold that there are certain things God cannot do because of his nature. Being morally perfect, he cannot commit an act of senseless cruelty, for example. God's omnipotence must then be understood as the power to do whatever is logically possible and consistent with God's own essential characteristics. Similar restrictions may have to be placed on the concept of omniscience.
Even with these qualifications God's power is still infinite in the sense of being unlimited by anything outside himself." [Philosophy of Religion, C. Stephen Evans, IVP:1982, p.33f]


"The question is a semantic issue." — Exactly. (+1, because no other answer actually mentioned it). I think all answers to this question will boil down to that, equivalent to the Omnipotence paradox: "Could God create a stone so heavy that even he could not lift it?".

This is exactly right. The question is another instance, as Ray says, of "can God create a boulder so heavy that He cannot lift it." It hides a logical contradiction semantically within the framing of the question and then pretends that God lacks a power because He cannot create a logical contradiction, whereas classical definitions of omnipotence exclude logical contradiction as powers. This should be the accepted answer.

The fact that God can do anything does not mean He will do everything.
Dirty example: the fact that you can now stand up and throw something away from your window does not mean you're willing to do it.
Off-topic: This is also my personal view on predestination. The fact that God can see the future does not mean He will actively do it.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
